# How to stream from a private m3u8 server using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, live-streaming

I've been using ffmpeg to stream m3u8 files to twitch, and similar platforms,
through this script:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

PRESET="ultrafast"
PLATFORM="rtmp://(platform_streaming_url)"
SOURCE="source of the stream(m3u8)"
STREAMING_KEY="platform_personal_streaming_key"

ffmpeg \
    -re -i "$SOURCE" -vcodec libx264 -preset $PRESET -maxrate 3000k -b:v 2500k \
    -bufsize 600k -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 60 -c:a aac -b:a 160k -ac 2 \
    -ar 44100 -f flv -s 1280x720 "$STREAMING_KEY/$PLATFORM"
```

But usualy the source of those streams are private, and to stream from private sources i have to use other solutions that take a lot of my computer resources.

So is there a way to stream through ffmpeg, knowing that i have the **credentials** of that private stream.

Comment: Depend on how “private” is implemented. If it’s a cookie, or http header, yes if it’s a drm key, no.

Comment: I think it's a cookie or something locally related, because this is how i activate the server: i get some key from a file that i download, and paste it in an html input in the provider's website then i get the **m3u** file to download. which has all the m3u8 files that i will to choose from to broadcast,

Comment: I’m not sure what “activate the server” means. But check the debug console, and look at the http headers.

Comment: ok, lets say i have the headers, or cookies. how would i activate them through ffmpeg

Comment: it's an IPTV server by the way

Comment: Try to receive the manifest with curl first.

Comment: I got a cookie with a name PHPSESSID, and only after the whole process of activating the server. i got a session key,

I don't know we can get the session key from curl or not